# how to convert single array into multiple nested array format for slice method use

Tags: javascript, algorithm, multidimensional-array, nested

[image]

I got the one-dimensional array list and wanna remake it like this below.

data = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17], ... ,[88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96]]

and then, I want to pick each of nested data[i] and slice the elements inside by 3, 6.

For last, I want to make new two arrays by pushing the sliced array.

e.g data[0]= [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

new_data1 = []
, new_data2 =[]

new_data1.pushing(data[0].slice(0,2))

new_data2.pushing(data[0].slice(3,8))

---

new_data1 = [0,1,2,9,10,11,19,20,21, ...]

new_data2 = [3,4,5,6,7,8,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,22,23,...]

This is what I want to make it. I can make a new array by using setState or hooks.

Comment: Provide an example final output for your input `[0, ... 96]`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96];

let lengths = [3, 6];
let batches = lengths.map(() => []);
for (let i = 0; array.length; i = 1 - i)
  batches[i] = batches[i].concat(array.splice(0, lengths[i]));
console.log(batches);
// let [new_data1, new_data2] = batches;
```

BTW, your example output is off by 1. `18` should be in the `new_data1`, not `new_data2`. Likewise `21` should move to `new_data2`

Comment: Oops! Miss typed. Thank you for reminding me, and appreciate your reply junvar

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```js
// grouping elements into 2-dimentional array
const grouped = data.reduce((prev, curr, index) => {
    const idx = parseInt(index / 9)
    if (prev[idx]) {
        prev[idx].push(curr)
    } else {
        prev[idx] = [curr]
    }
    return prev
}, [])

// generate new arrays
const dataset1 = [], dataset2 = []
for (let group of grouped) {
    dataset1.push(...group.slice(0, 3))
    dataset2.push(...group.slice(3, 9))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do

```js
// Generate input sample data from 0 to 96 [0, 1, 2, .... 95]
const data = new Array(96).fill(0).map((_,i) => i);

let new_data1 = [];
let new_data2 = [];
let i = 0;

while (i < (96 - 9)) {
  new_data1.push(...data.slice(i, i+3));
  new_data2.push(...data.slice(i+3, i+9))
  i += 9;
}


console.log('data1-->', JSON.stringify(new_data1));
console.log('data2-->', JSON.stringify(new_data2));
```

Comment: I haven't thought in this way. You are amazing Siva Kondapi Venkata. Thank you for your reply

Comment: @Youncho Kim, Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

You said one-dimensional array but the data is a two-dimensional array. So I make an example with two dimensional array:

```js
const input = Array.from({length: 11}, (v1,i1) => Array.from({length: 9}, (v2, i2) => i1*9+i2));
// [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17],...,[90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98]]

const new_data1 = [];
const new_data2 = [];
for (const values of input) {
    new_data1.push(...values.slice(0, 3));
    new_data2.push(...values.slice(3));
}

// res:
// new_data1 = [0, 1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 18, 19, 20, ..., 72, 73, 74, 81, 82, 83, 90, 91, 92]
// new_data2 = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 13, 14, ..., 87, 88, 89, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98]
```